# is it possible to view a recursive tree of files in a folder of a certain file type?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a series of folders and files and I would like to copy a list of the folder and files structure and containing files. Is there a way to do this on a mac in the terminal or otherwise?

This looks like a good option http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/ but I can't see if it supports file types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I just came across the pacakge called `tree` within `homebrew`. It is rather nice and has many options for output. If you have `homebrew`, you just run

```
brew install tree
```

Then you can type `tree -help` to see how it works. Recommended!

```
tree v1.7.0 (c) 1996 - 2014 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher
```

**Original Answer**

You can start a Terminal and run a command like this:

```
ls -R | grep ":" | sed -e 's/://' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

which gives output like this:

```
 |-CocoaDialog.app
 |---Contents
 |-----MacOS
 |-----Resources
 |-------Inputbox.nib
 |-------MainMenu.nib
 |-------Msgbox.nib
 |-------PopUpButton.nib
 |-------Progressbar.nib
 |-------SecureInputbox.nib
 |-------Textbox.nib
 |-OpenTerminalHere.app
```

If you want to copy this, simply add "| pbcopy" to the command above and everything it outputs will be saved in your Clipboard and you can then paste into Email, MS-Word documents or wherever you like.

```
ls -R | grep ":" | sed -e 's/://' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/' | pbcopy
```

Or you may be happier with something simpler, like this:

```
find `pwd`
/Users/mark/bin 
/Users/mark/bin/.DS_Store
/Users/mark/bin/a
/Users/mark/bin/AirPortWirelessPower
/Users/mark/bin/analyze.awk
/Users/mark/bin/analyze_fs
/Users/mark/bin/apachestart
/Users/mark/bin/atime
```

Or you can specifiy file names to "find" like this:

```
find `pwd` -name "*.doc"
/Users/mark/Documents/Correspondence/Anderson 0001.doc
/Users/mark/Documents/Correspondence/Anderson 0002.doc
/Users/mark/Documents/Correspondence/Anderson 0003.doc
```

You can add "| pbcopy" to all of these to copy the output to the Clipboard.